# Remarkable limit involving $m_p=\log_p(p^{x_1} + \cdots + p^{x_n})-\log_p(n)$

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis, st.statistics, sequences-and-series, limits-and-convergence

It is easy to prove that
$\lim_{p\rightarrow 1} m_p = (x_1 + \cdots + x_n)/n$. The following fact about the derivative of $m_p$ with respect to $p$ is also elementary:
$$m'_p =\frac{dm_p}{dp}
=\frac{1}{p \log p}\cdot\Big[\frac{x_1p^{x_1}+\cdots+x_np^{x_n}}{p_1^{x_1}+\cdots+p_n^{x_n}}-m_p\Big].$$
My interest in this is to create an alternative to the power mean, called the *exponential mean*: see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3800733/inequalities-for-generalized-means) and [here](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/alternative-to-the-arithmetic-geometric-and-harmonic-means). The limit I am interested in is $\lim_{p\rightarrow 1} m'_p$. Using WolframAlpha, I computed the limit for $n=2,3,4,5$ (see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20%28%28x%20p%5Ex%20%2B%20y%20p%5Ey%20%2B%20z%20p%5Ez%20%2B%20w%20p%5Ew%20%2B%20u%20p%5Eu%29%2F%28p%5Ex%20%2B%20p%5Ey%20%2Bp%5Ez%20%2B%20p%5Ew%20%2B%20p%5Eu%29%20-%20%28log%28p%5Ex%20%2B%20p%5Ey%20%2Bp%5Ez%20%2B%20p%5Ew%20%2Bp%5Eu%29-log%285%29%29%2F%28log%20p%29%29%2F%28log%20p%29%20as%20p-%3E1)) and the following remarkable pattern emerges:
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow 1} m'_p=\frac{1}{2n^2}\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}(x_i-x_j)^2.$$
How do you go about formally proving this fact? It does not sound elementary to me. Also, it sounds like $m_p$ is a strictly increasing function of $p$ (its derivative beeing positive everywhere, with $m'_0 =+\infty$ and $m'_\infty =0$) unless all the $x_i$'s are identical.

**Update**

In short, $m_1$ is the arithmetic mean and $m'_1$ is half the empirical variance of $x_1,\cdots,x_n$. I tried to see if such simple formulas existed for the power mean $M_p$, but I could not find anything interesting other than the well known fact that $M_1=m_1$ is the arithmetic mean. It would be interesting to see how the second and third derivatives of $m_p$ at $p=1$ are linked to the higher empirical moments of $x_1,\cdots,x_n$.

Comment: The 5th example of the [quasi-arithmetic mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-arithmetic_mean) wikipedia page appears to be your expression $m_p$, which may be useful.

Comment: Thanks for asking a well written and very polite question. I think, though, that this is going to just yield to L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I actually researched the mean in question in more details before posting, but I could not find anything leading to either a statement or proof of my result regarding $m'_1$.

Comment: I found it a bit confusing when reading this question that it started with a computation involving an apparently undefined quantity $m_p$.  I eventually noticed that it was defined in the title, but, if you ever have occasion to edit, it may be appropriate to reproduce the definition in the body.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$\newcommand\bar\overline$
Letting $t:=\ln p$, we see that the limit in question is the limit of
$$d(t):=\frac1t\Big(\sum_1^n x_j e^{tx_j}\Big/\sum_1^n e^{tx_j}-m_{e^t}\Big)$$
as $t\to0$.
Next, letting
$\bar x:=\frac1n\,\sum_1^n x_j$, $\bar{x^2}:=\frac1n\,\sum_1^n x_j^2$, and $s^2=\bar{x^2}-\bar x^2$, we have
$$\sum_1^n x_j e^{tx_j}=\sum_1^n x_j (1+tx_j+o(t))
=n(\bar x+t\bar{x^2})+o(t),$$
$$\sum_1^n e^{tx_j}=\sum_1^n (1+tx_j+o(t))
=n(1+t\bar x)+o(t),$$
$$m_{e^t}=\log_{e^t}\Big(\frac1n\,\sum_1^n e^{tx_j}\Big) \\
=\log_{e^t}(1+t\bar x+t^2\bar{x^2}/2+o(t^2)) \\
=\tfrac1t\,\ln(1+t\bar x+t^2\bar{x^2}/2+o(t^2)) \\
=\bar x+ts^2/2+o(t).$$
So,
$$d(t)=\frac1t\Big(\frac{\bar x+t\bar{x^2}}{1+t\bar x}+o(t)-\bar x-ts^2/2\Big) \\
=\frac1t\Big((\bar x+t\bar{x^2})(1-t\bar x)+o(t)-\bar x-ts^2/2\Big) \\ 
=s^2/2+o(1). $$
So, the limit in question is
$$s^2/2
=\frac1{4n^2}\sum_{1\le i,j\le n}(x_i-x_j)^2 \\ 
=\frac1{4n^2}\sum_{1\le i,j\le n,\ i\ne j}(x_i-x_j)^2 \\ 
=\frac1{2n^2}\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}(x_i-x_j)^2,$$
as conjectured.

---

*Details on the first equality in the last three-line display*: The left-hand side of that equality is $\frac12\,Var\,X$, where $X$ is any random variable whose distribution is $\frac1n\,\sum_1^n\delta_{x_j}$, where $\delta_a$ is the Dirac probability measure at point $a$. The right-hand side of that equality is $$\frac14\,E(X-X')^2=\frac14\,Var(X-X')=\frac12\,Var\,X,$$
where $X'$ is an independent copy of $X$.

Of course, that equality can also be checked by straightforward algebraic calculations.

Comment: Thanks Losif. Still trying to figure out why WA gives half your value, see https://dsc.news/2FXbHpX when $n=2$.

Comment: @VincentGranville : Sorry, I thought $m_p$ was defined as $\bar x$. The necessary correction has now been made, and your conjecture holds.

Comment: @Losif: thank you. One of my other problems is to prove (or disprove) that $m_p \leq m_q$ if $p<q$. This inequality holds for the power mean $M_p$, wondering if it is true too for the expo mean $m_p$. I'm wondering if I should open another question regarding this, or maybe you have a sense that it might be trivial.

Comment: @VincentGranville : Yes, $m_p$ is nondecreasing in $p>0$, because $L(t):=\ln Ee^{tX}$ is convex in $t$, with $L(0)=0$. (The first letter in my first name is, not L, but the upper case of i.)

Comment: Thank you, and I apologize for the typo in your first name.

Comment: I won't edit to bump this to the front page, but (as I think you know but others may not) MathJax lets you use `\label` and `\eqref`, so that there is no need to refer to things like "the first equality in the last three-line display."

Comment: @LSpice : Thank you for the reminder.